# Declare footnotes outside the paragraph text

Tags: footnotes

Fellow typesetters,

I have such a stupid problem: I want to *declare footnotes outside the
paragraph text* (as in the MWE below). I believe this makes the TeX
file much easier to read. The problem is that even though the `.tex`
is compiled without errors, footnote reference symbols all come out
zeroes. The `\footref`s don't seem to "catch" the footnote
declarations. The footnotes must be declared in the `.aux` file since
the PDF is produced without errors.

I have already tried changing order with the footnote declarations
above the paragraph.

Declaring the footnotes with `\footnote` instead of `\footnotemark` solves the nubering but the symbols show up as characters in paragraphs of their own.

I don't want to use the optional argument approach but stick with
automatic numbering to avoid issues with page breaks.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[multiple]{footmisc}
\usepackage{footnote}

\begin{document}

Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices
posuere cubilia Curae\footref{note:lockout}. Lorem ipsum dolor sit
amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam a libero gravida, dignissim
neque id, commodo libero. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus
orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia
Curae\footref{note:dbversioner}\footref{note:lockin}, ipsum dolor sit
amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 

\footnotetext{Det finns.\label{note:lockout}}

\footnotetext{Vid uppgradering av
  databasen.\label{note:dbversioner}}

\footnotetext{Ett annat exempel.\label{note:lockin}}

\end{document}
```

I compile the original document with XeLaTeX. The MWE have the same
problems wether I use XeLaTeX or pdfLaTeX.

I know there's an obvious answer but now I feel stuck. Anyone up for
some easy points?

Cheers

Comment: Check out the [`sepfootnotes`](http://ctan.org/pkg/sepfootnotes) package

Comment: Sweet. That hit the spot. Put it in an answer for credit.

Comment: @clemens: sure. close it. That seems right.